# Why I recieve NullPointer exception after evaluation isNull() to false

Tags: javafx

I try to prepare table view cell calback.
I have problem with when bindings.  Each time if I check any property  with isNull() or isNotNull() after evaluation to  not null  I recieve null pointer exception when try to access data.

```
    this.columnRelationSimLeft.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Relationship, Image>, ObservableValue<Image>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Image> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Relationship, Image> param) {
            if (Objects.isNull(param) || Objects.isNull(param.getValue())) return null;
            ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
            image.bind(Bindings.when(param.getValue().simLeftProperty().isNull()
                            .or(param.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty().isNull()))
                    .then(DefaultImageProvider.INSTANCE.getImageFrom(SimAge.ADULT, SimGender.F))
                    .otherwise(param.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty())
            );
            return image;
        }
    });
```

on given example  null pointer exception is fired on

"param.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty().isNull()"

photoProperty itself cannot be null because for each property I have declaration in class like this

```
  public class Sim {
    private ObjectProperty<Image> photo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
  }
```

i had this problem also before qhen I created bindings for other purpose. Each time called property.isNull() it goes to otherwise method, so I always have nullpointer exception

Comment: faintly remember that all parts of the when bindings are always evaluated - so you can't exclude nulls the way you do

Comment: @kleopatra Actually, `when(...)`, `then(...)`, and `otherwise(...)` are all called here unconditionally at the time the binding is established (not when it is evaluated). If `getSimLeft()` returns null at the time the binding is established, this will throw a NPE.

Comment: @James_D yeah, was unclear (in thoughts and writing :) - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

All the terms in a `Bindings.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...)` construct are evaluated at the time the binding is established irrespective of the condition in the `when(...)` clause.

In other words, to *create* the binding, you call the three methods `when(...)`, `then(...)`, and `otherwise(...)` and pass values to those methods. The value you pass to the `otherwise(...)` method is `param.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty()`: if `getSimLeft()` returns null, this will throw a null pointer exception.

Instead, you can manually observe the `simLeftProperty()` and rebind the image when it changes:

```
param.getValue().simLeftProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    image.unbind();
    if (newValue == null) {
        image.set(DefaultImageProvider.INSTANCE.getImageFrom(SimAge.ADULT, SimGender.F));
    } else {
        image.bind(Bindings
              .when(newValue.photoProperty().isNull())
              .then(DefaultImageProvider.INSTANCE.getImageFrom(SimAge.ADULT, SimGender.F))
              .otherwise(newValue.photoProperty())
        );
    }
};
```

Note that the cell value factory merely needs to return an `Observable<Image>`, and `Binding<Image>` is a subinterface of that. So it's enough here to return the binding directly; there's no need to create a separate `ObjectProperty<Image>` and bind it to the binding. Probably the most efficient approach is:

```
this.columnRelationSimLeft.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ObjectBinding<>() {
    WeakChangeListener<Sim> listener = new WeakChangeListener<>((obs, oldSim, newSim) -> {
        if (oldSim != null) unbind(oldSim.photoProperty());
        if (newSim != null) bind(newSim.photoProperty());
    });
    {
        if (cellData.getValue() != null) {
            bind(cellData.getValue().simLeftProperty());
            cellData.getValue().simLeftProperty().addListener(listener);
            if (cellData.getValue().getSimLeft() != null) {
                bind(cellData.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty());
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Image computeValue() {
        if (cellData.getValue() == null) return null ;
        if (cellData.getValue().getSimLeft() == null) return null ;
        return cellData.getValue().getSimLeft().getPhoto();
    }
});
```

(I'm assuming here that `getSimLeft()` returns an object of type `Sim`. If that's not correct, just update the type of the `WeakListener` accordingly.)

Comment: the problem is that this is binding in table view. So it will be  contain multiple listeners.  So i'm worry about performance.  Could you explain me the problem with when().then() ? Why it doesnt works for me ?

Comment: @VANILKA 1. Don’t worry about performance unless you have evidence it’s an issue. 2. As I said, all elements of the `Bindings.when(…).then(…).otherwise(…)` are evaluated. So `param.getValue().getSimLeft().photoProperty()` is evaluated even when `param.getValue().getSimLeft()` is null.

Comment: But there is no sense if simLeftProperty is null it should go to then and not otherwise.. it seems like when clos return false even its null.. so i dont understand why

Comment: @VANILKA I think, because if the resulting value is an `Observable` of some kind, it needs to be observed, it ends up being evaluated no matter what. It possibly could have been written to avoid that, but the bottom line is that it isn't written that way. It is evaluated, and that's why you get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @VANILKA Actually, it's simpler than that. `getSimLeft().photoProperty()` has to be evaluated when `otherwise(...)` is invoked (i.e. when the binding is established, not evaluated), and I'm guessing `getSimLeft()` returns null at that time. If the API had defined `then(...)` and `otherwise(...)` to take a `Supplier<T>` or `Supplier<Observable<T>>` instead of just `<T>` or <Observable<T>>`, it might have been possible for them to create the methods you want to use, but it didn't define them that way.

Comment: I still dont understant. I check gestSimLeft property with isNull for example.  so if is null then (....)  if not null otherwise(..). And in my case simleft is null and it goes to otherwise(.. )and not to then(..). this is my problem.

Comment: @VANILKA What value are you passing to the `otherwise(...)` method? You are calling that method (as well as the `then(...)` method) *when you are setting up the binding*, not when the binding is being evaluated.

Comment: hmm.. so this is not like normal if/else ? I would like to use it like if someProperty is null then do something otherwise to something else. I canoot use it for this purpose ?

Comment: @VANILKA These are just regular Java methods like any other Java method. You can use them in the way you describe - I do that in my solution - just not "two levels deep" as you are trying. What is wrong with the solution I propose?